# How to in-place assign an item to a class containing a list, without inheritance?

Tags: python

Why do I get `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` with the following code:

```
class MyOwnList():
    def __init__(self, a_list):
        self.list = a_list
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.list[index]
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.list[index]= value

L2 = MyOwnList([])
L2[0] = "a"
```

I know I can derive from `list` or `UserList`, but I want to use composition not inheritance.

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you get that error? You're just proxying to the default implementation of `list.__setitem__`, which doesn't automatically change the length of the list. If you want some different behaviour (e.g. extending the list up to the specified index _then_ inserting) you need to _write that_. Also I'd recommend extending [`collections.abc.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence); even though you're composing the result should still match that interface.

Comment: You may be getting confused because dicts don't behave like this, i.e. you can set keys on dicts that didn't exist before.

Comment: Alex Hall is right and I am still confused.

Comment: What exactly did you _expect_ to happen here? Given `l = []`, what should `l[0] = "foo"` do? What should `L2[0] = "a"` do, if different? Maybe you don't actually want list-like behaviour at all, it's not clear - how will you _use_ `MyOwnList`?

Comment: Ok, I got the error part; there is no `L2[0]`.

Comment: This is what you're actually doing, without all that class stuff: `self.list = []`, `self.list[0] = "a"`. Obviously you cannot do that.

Comment: I want to compose and delegate list methods, which requires `__getattr__` I think.

Comment: If you want to delegate to the list, the code's doing the right thing (at least for the methods defined). The error is _coming from the list_, because how you're interacting with `MyOwnList` isn't a valid interaction with the vanilla list it delegates to.

Answer (score -1):

This code works after adding `__getattr__`

```
class MyOwnList():
    def __init__(self, a_list):
        self.list = a_list
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.list[index]
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.list[index]= value
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.list, name)

L2 = MyOwnList([])
L2.append(10)
print(L2[0])
L2[0] = "a"
print(L2[0])
```

Comment: That _doesn't_ actually fix the `IndexError` you reported. I'd suggest just deleting the question.